# Oauth on webview / embedded browser

Tags: firebase, oauth, google-oauth, firebase-authentication

Google's OAuth has blocked request from web view.

However, most of my user enter my website via QR code scanner app (QR code scanner app in general). Qr code scanner app then open webview to my page. User won't be to login or signup through social network (OAuth authentication). I would like to find a way to work this out. Many users have this problem and call to our support.

I am finding the solution or work around to this. I use Google's Firebase, therefore, I could't use other authentication service.

Here is the list of options I can think of..

- launch normal browser if webview is detected.. (I'm not sure if this
  is possible, the webview is own by the QR code scanner app, I tried
  many ways and it didn't work)
- set http request header on client to show that the client is NOT requesting from a webview (not possible due to Google's policy "Do not mislead Google about an application's operating environment.")